# Error in jQuery.post response

Tags: jquery, post, return

I'm using joomla and chronoform for building my own site. Now I've a strange problem.

For filling a listbox I'm using a call via jQuery ( herebelow an abstract ) :

```
......
    PostVar=[val1,'1'];
    jQuery.post("/includes/ListNew.php",{PostVar: PostVar}, function (response) {
    mystack=JSON.parse(response);
    for (var i=0;i<mystack.length; i++) { 
......
```

I'm expecting to receive a JSON string but I receive a string like this one

```
"// [{"userid":"24","email":"uso@gmail.com"}]\n"
```

and this causes an error.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Its not a valid Json response or even a valid String. How you are generating this?

Comment: i generate using :

return (json_encode($row) );

where $row is an array of values 

Paolo